# Typescript tsc --version still 0.9.5

Tags: typescript, updates

So this is a minor issue, but I've installed VS 2013 Update 2 and my Typescript compiler still says 0.9.5 instead off what I hoped to be 1.0.x by now.

Any ideas what I need to install to get this fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uninstall older versions of TypeScript from the control panel.

Also you do `where tsc` to find out which `tsc` is actually going to execute.

Comment: On Windows you can just use `where tsc` in any command prompt.

Comment: The above answer helped me as when I run "where tsc" I realised that there was a Microsoft SDK typescript version in my path at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Typescript

Deleting the above folder and running again "where tsc" revealed the latest version.